# Eager loading same model multiple times in a model

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, database-normalization

I have a Model named Player with 'id' and 'shortname'.
I have another Model named Team with 'id', 'teamname', 'player_1_id', 'player_2_id' and 'player_3_id'.

I am trying to use relations:

// in Model Team

```
public function players()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Player', 'id','player_1_id')
      ->hasOne('App\Player', 'id','player_2_id')
      ->hasOne('App\Player', 'id','player_3_id');
}
```

// In controller

`$resource = Team::with('players')->get();` doesnt work.

In this case, Which is the best(fastest) way to use eagerloading?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read about database normalization. It does not make sense to store `player_1_id`, `player_2_id` and `player_3_id` in teams database. What if team will contain 20 players? You will create another fields?

You should either add `team_id` into Player model (in case players always belongs to only one team) or create extra table where you will store connections between players and teams.

Comment: Thanks Marcin. I read about database normalization, and understood, as you said,, that i should use just player_id, using more rows if needed. But, that will incrise the number of rows a lot. Would it not slow down the queries, having lots of more rows? (in my real project i have 20 players per team :P)

Comment: @Attorn Glad I could help you. It's better to track design mistakes just at the beginning when you have no code than find them when you already have the whole application working